# HTACCESS - upper case to lower case with exception

Tags: apache, .htaccess, exception, redirect, configuration

All URL paths must be in lower case
When URL path has uppercase, redirect with 301 answer code to URL path only with lower case

I need to rule out the case where the uppercase letters in the url must stay for example

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]   
RewriteRule . ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]
```

This code in htaccess propably change upper case in url to lower case but i have no idea how to create exception for url like:
https://example.com/testcase/1937Kdx88Ui9Ac
where i need lower and upper case.

Comment: How did you get on with my answer? I believe you left a comment earlier saying that it worked (but for some reason deleted it?). If this resolved the issue for you then please "accept it" (grey/green checkmark) on the left below the voting arrows to help other readers. Also consider upvotng answers you find helpful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]   
> RewriteRule . ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]
> ```

You don't need the separate *condition* here. The check for uppercase letters should be performed in the `RewriteRule` directive itself. For example, the above can be "simplified" to:

```
RewriteRule [A-Z] ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]
```

You can then add "exceptions" (*conditions*) to exclude certain URLs from being converted. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/testcase/1937Kdx88Ui9Ac
RewriteRule [A-Z] ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]
```

Multiple exceptions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/testcase/1937Kdx88Ui9Ac
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/testcase/FOO
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/testcase/BAR    
RewriteRule [A-Z] ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]
```

The `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* (2nd argument to the `RewriteCond` directive) negates the expression, so it is successful when the expression does *not* match.

The `=` operator makes it a lexicographical (exact match) string comparison instead of the normal regex.

Note that you will need to clear your browser cache, since any erroneous 301 (permanent) redirects will have been cached by the browser. Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

NB: The use of the `lc` rewrite map requires that this has already been configured in the server config.